# RowHeaderTemplate and NewItemPlaceholder

Tags: wpf, templates, datagrid

I'm trying to put an image visible or hidden in rowHeader. It's working for normal row, but for NewItemPlaceHolder it's always visible. How I can hide image for NewItemPlaceHolder?

```
<DataGrid.RowHeaderTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="20" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, 
                                  AncestorType={x:Type DataGridRow}}, 
                                  Path=Item.xmlId}"/>
                        <Image Grid.Column="1"
                               Source="/MYAppli;component/Res/003_Fermer.png"
                               ToolTip="ERROR"
                               Margin="0"
                               Width="11" Height="11" 
                               >
                        <Image.Style>
                            <Style TargetType="{x:Type Image}">
                                <Style.Triggers>
                                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, 
                                  AncestorType={x:Type DataGridRow}}, 
                                  Path=Item.HasError}" Value="true" >
                                <Setter Property="Visibility"  Value="Visible" />
                            </DataTrigger>
                                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, 
                                  AncestorType={x:Type DataGridRow}}, 
                                  Path=Item.HasError}" Value="false" >
                                        <Setter Property="Visibility"  Value="Hidden" />
                                    </DataTrigger>
                                </Style.Triggers>
                                </Style>
                        </Image.Style>
                    </Image>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
```

[image: NewItemPlaceholder]

Comment: Here you can find sample, how to restyle it http://stackoverflow.com/a/20651622/1979354

Comment: How access to my image with this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I do this following :

```
        <Style x:Key="DataGridRowHeader" TargetType="DataGridRowHeader">
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="9" />
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding}" Value="{x:Static CollectionView.NewItemPlaceholder}">
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRowHeader}">
                            <Button Background="LightGray" IsEnabled="False">
                            <Image Source="/MYAppli;component/Res/031_Plus.png"
                                   Height="10"
                                   Width="10"></Image>
                            </Button>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
```

[image: NewItemPlaceHolder]